# Flask error after pressing sell button CS50 finance

Tags: python, flask, cs50

I have a problem with identifying the reason behind this problem. Here's the error message:

```
ERROR: Exception on /sell [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1463, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 872, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 870, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 855, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/workspaces/87340802/finance/helpers.py", line 48, in decorated_function
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/workspaces/87340802/finance/app.py", line 273, in sell
    return render_template("sell.html", stocks=stocks)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 149, in render_template
    template = app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1081, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1010, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, globals)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 969, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 137, in load
    code = environment.compile(source, name, filename)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 768, in compile
    self.handle_exception(source=source_hint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 936, in handle_exception
    raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
  File "/workspaces/87340802/finance/templates/sell.html", line 5, in template
    {% endblock %}
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'endblock'.
```

And my code(app.py):

```
import os

from cs50 import SQL
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session
from flask_session import Session
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash

from helpers import apology, login_required, lookup, usd

# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__)

# Custom filter
app.jinja_env.filters["usd"] = usd

# Configure session to use filesystem (instead of signed cookies)
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

# Configure CS50 Library to use SQLite database
db = SQL("sqlite:///finance.db")


@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    """Ensure responses aren't cached"""
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Expires"] = 0
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    return response


@app.route("/")
@login_required
def index():
    """Show portfolio of stocks"""
    # Get user's stocks and shares
    stocks = db.execute("SELECT symbol, SUM(shares) as total_shares FROM transactions WHERE user_id = :user_id GROUP BY symbol HAVING total_shares > 0",
                        user_id=session["user_id"])

    # Get user's cash balance
    cash = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = :user_id", user_id=session["user_id"])[0]["cash"]

    # Initialize varaibles for total values
    total_value = cash
    grand_total = cash

    # Iterate over stocks and add price and total value
    for stock in stocks:
        quote = lookup(stock["symbol"])
        stock["name"] = quote["name"]
        stock["price"] = quote["price"]
        stock["value"] = stock["price"] * stock["total_shares"]
        total_value += stock["value"]
        grand_total += stock["value"]

    return render_template("index.html", stocks=stocks, cash=cash, total_value=total_value, grand_total=grand_total)



@app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def buy():
    """Buy shares of stock"""
    if request.method == "POST":
        symbol = request.form.get("symbol").upper()
        shares = request.form.get("shares")
        if not symbol:
            return apology("Symbol is not valid")
        elif not shares or not shares.isdigit() or int(shares) <= 0:
            return apology("Choose an integer number greater than 0 shares")

        quote = lookup(symbol)
        if quote is None:
            return apology("symbol not found")

        price = quote["price"]
        total_cost = int(shares) * price
        cash = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = :user_id", user_id=session["user_id"])[0]["cash"]

        if cash < total_cost:
            return apology("insufficient funds")

        # Update users table
        db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash - :total_cost WHERE id = :user_id",
                   total_cost=total_cost, user_id=session["user_id"])

        # Add the purschase to the history table
        db.execute("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id, symbol, shares, price) VALUES (:user_id, :symbol, :shares, :price)",
                   user_id=session["user_id"], symbol=symbol, shares=shares, price=price)

        flash(f"Bought {shares} shares of {symbol} for {usd(total_cost)}!")
        return redirect("/")
    else:
        return render_template("buy.html")



@app.route("/history")
@login_required
def history():
    """Show history of transactions"""
    # Query database for user's transactions, ordered by most recent first
    transactions = db.execute(
        "SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE user_id = :user_id ORDER BY timestamp DESC", user_id=session["user_id"])

    # Render history page with transactions
    return render_template("history.html", transactions=transactions)


@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    """Log user in"""

    # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Ensure username was submitted
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return apology("must provide username", 403)

        # Ensure password was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            return apology("must provide password", 403)

        # Query database for username
        rows = db.execute(
            "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", request.form.get("username")
        )

        # Ensure username exists and password is correct
        if len(rows) != 1 or not check_password_hash(
            rows[0]["hash"], request.form.get("password")
        ):
            return apology("invalid username and/or password", 403)

        # Remember which user has logged in
        session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]

        # Redirect user to home page
        return redirect("/")

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")


@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    """Log user out"""

    # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    # Redirect user to login form
    return redirect("/")


@app.route("/quote", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def quote():
    """Get stock quote."""
    if request.method == "POST":
        symbol = request.form.get("symbol")
        quote = lookup(symbol)
        if not quote:
            return apology("invalid symbol", 400)
        return render_template("quote.html", quote=quote)
    else:
        return render_template("quote.html")




@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register user"""
    # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    # User reached route via POST
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Ensure username was submitted
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return apology("must provide username", 400)

        # Ensure password was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            return apology("must provide password", 400)

        # Ensure password confirmation was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("confirmation"):
            return apology("must confirm password", 400)

        # Ensure password and confirmation match
        elif request.form.get("password") != request.form.get("confirmation"):
            return apology("passwords do not match", 400)

        # Query database for username
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", request.form.get("username"))

        # Ensure username does not already exist
        if len(rows) != 0:
            return apology("username already exists", 400)

        # Insert new user into database
        db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES(?, ?)",
                   request.form.get("username"), generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password")))

        # Query database for newly inserted user
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", request.form.get("username"))

        # Remember which user has logged in
        session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]

        # Redirect user to home page
        return redirect("/")

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("register.html")

c
@app.route("/sell", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def sell():
    """Sell shares of stock"""
    # Get user's stocks
    stocks = db.execute("SELECT symbol, SUM(shares) as total_shares FROM transactions WHERE user_id = :user_id GROUP BY symbol HAVING total_shares > 0",
                        user_id=session["user_id"])
    # if the user submits the form
    if request.method == "POST":
        symbol = request.form.get("symbol").upper()
        shares = request.form.get("shares")
        if not symbol:
            return apology("Symbol is not valid")
        elif not shares or not shares.isdigit() or int(shares) <= 0:
            return apology("Please provide an integer number greater than 0 shares")
        else:
            shares = int(shares)

        for stock in stocks:
            if stock["symbol"] == symbol:
                if stock["total_shares"] < shares:
                    return apology("not enough shares")
                else:
                    # Get quote
                    quote = lookup(symbol)
                    if quote is None:
                        return apology("symbol not found")
                    price = quote["price"]
                    total_sale = shares * price

                    # Update users table
                    db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash + :total_sale WHERE id = :user_id",
                               total_sale=total_sale, user_id=session["user_id"])

                    # Add the sale to the history table
                    db.execute("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id, symbol, shares, price) VALUES (:user_id, :symbol, :shares, :price)",
                               user_id=session["user_id"], symbol=symbol, shares=-shares, price=price)

                    flash(f"Successfully sold {shares} shares of {symbol} for {usd(total_sale)}!")
                    return redirect("/")

        return apology("symbol not found")

    # If the user visits the page
    else:
        return render_template("sell.html", stocks=stocks)
```

I spent a considerable amount of time trying to identify the underlying reason behind the issue, examining every possible aspect such as typo or potential flaws in the logical flow. Unfortunately, to no avail. So, I apologize if any confusion still exists in my question, as this is my first time asking here. Any help appreciated!

sell.html: `

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{$ block title %}
    Sell Shares
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="/sell" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="symbol">Symbol</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="symbol" name="symbol">
                <option value="">Select stock</option>
                {% for stock in stocks %}
                    <option value="{{ stock.symbol }}">{{ stock.name }} ({{ stock.symbol }})</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="shares">Shares</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="shares" name="shares" placeholder="Number of shares" type="number">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sell</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

`

Comment: The problem happens in `sell.html`.  Show us that template file.

Comment: The error is `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'endblock'`, which is complaining about the syntax in one of your Jinja templates. You would need to inspect the relevant template for errors. It looks like you have an `{% endblock %}` statement that doesn't match up with a corresponding `{% block %}`.